# How can I set path and mark folder as root generated sources(Intellij IDE) from gradle script?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

If I use this config:

```
sourceSets.configureEach { sourceSet ->
    tasks.named(sourceSet.compileJavaTaskName).configure {
        options.annotationProcessorGeneratedSourcesDirectory = file("$buildDir/generated/sources/java")
    }
}
```

I have generated classes in `$buildDir/generated/sources/java` folder

but if I try repeat this like this:

```
idea {
    module {
        generatedSourceDirs += file("$buildDir/generated/sources/java")
    }
}
```

not happens.

I need set path and mark ths folder as `root generated sources` from `gradle` script

Comment: Try https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-get-intellij-to-recognize-gradle-generated-sources-dir/16847/5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intellij IDE not see generated classes in gradle project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53911918/intellij-ide-not-see-generated-classes-in-gradle-project)